# "Unflag" a Question?

Tags: support, flagging

Any way to unflag a question? I flagged a question (AND left a comment) a bit less than an hour ago, but after my comment, the poster came back and added some good details - but my flag hasn't been reviewed yet.

I don't think that this question is worthy of flagging any longer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About the best thing for it is to flag it again saying nevermind, or hit the Comms Room chat-room to hunt up a 10K user. If they can see the flag (some are visible) they can mark it as invalid.

Comment: They'd need two 10k users to mark it invalid... But that does work.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to think the moderators only take flags as indicators that a post *might* need attention, and actually think about the specifics of the situation before acting on it... We don't have an overwhelming quantity of flags, so as long as you raise them in good faith it's no bother to us. If a flag doesn't get handled quickly, it's because there's no mods around (there's only a handful of us, and half are in the EST timezone).

Comment: Yup - pretty much if your flag makes no sense the worst thing that will happen is we'll mark it as declined.  Generally though if you spot a lousy question that can be improved you can downvote it and leave a comment, then when the poster fixes it just reverse your downvote :)